# Auto Assign Role weight

Tags: 7, users

I am using [Auto Assign Role Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) to allow users to choose their role during registration. Block to choose role appears as first block, before the default fields (username, email and password).

Is there a way to move AAR block to the bottom, after the default fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can reorder any Drupal form elements by altering its `#weight` property. To make the auto assign element appear above the other account registration elements just adjust its weight lighter.

This can be done in `hook_form_user_register_form_alter()` invocation:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Set the autoassignrole_user element 1 unit lighter than account form element
  $form['autoassignrole_user']['#weight'] = $form['account']['#weight'] - 1;
}
```